# Analog of ngTransclude in Angular.Dart

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I'm trying to figure out how to make a component render its children.

So I can compile:

```html
<my-component>
  <div id="child"></div>
</my-component>
```

into something like this:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <!-- some component stuff -->
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Is there something like ngTransclude in Angular.Dart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AngularDart uses Shadow DOM in place of ngTransclude.  This is one of the ways we are pushing Angular into the browser with emerging web standards.

Adding a `<content>` tag instead your component's template will cause the child element to be placed there.

e.g. in your example `<my-component>`'s template might look like:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <!-- some component stuff -->
  <content></content>
</div>
```

For even more awesomeness, you can use Shadow DOM's content selectors as well to control which child elements are displayed.