# How does AngularDart dependency injection work?

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I have an component that needs to access its root element from the Dart code. By reading [Differences between Angular.js and Angular.dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993377/differences-between-angular-js-and-angular-dart) here on SO and grepping around in the AngularDart source code I figured out that what I need is to provide a constructor with explicitly typed arguments. If one of the arguments has type `dom.Element`, it will be given the reference to my components root by the Angular injector. (Failing to have types on the constructor arguments results in an exception `NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'simpleName'` being thrown from deep down in Angular internals.) My code now looks like this:

```dart
@ng.NgComponent (
    selector: 'math',
    templateUrl: 'packages/embarassing_name_of_my_package/math/math_component.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MathComponent {
  ng.Scope _scope;
  dom.Element _element;
  ng.NgModel _ngModel;
  ng.NodeAttrs _attrs;

  MathComponent(this._scope, this._element, this._ngModel, this._attrs);

  …
}
```

with `ng` and `dom` being

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart' as ng;
import 'dart:html' as dom;
```

Now the question. How do I best discover those special types that the injector reacts to?

Additionally, I'd like to know: Is it documented somewhere? Where? If not, where in the AngularDart source is the injector being configured to behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are registered using the `Module.type()` method (or factory, value).

You can take a look at [Angular.dart source - search for 'type('](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/search?q=%22type%28%22&type=Code)
[like lib/core/module.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/0615456ef7836b215dc56bd2dc3abc09806e6859/lib/core/module.dart)

(Please ignore the results where `type` is not the function name)

When a constructor or a method called by Angular needs a parameter DI looks up its registered types/values/factories and uses a provided instance (value) or creates a new instance (type) or uses the result that a factory returns and injects it.