# How does Dependency injection work in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Say I have a class, Logger, which is not a component, which uses ServiceA (marked as Injectable). Logger's constructor look like:

```
Logger(this._logger);
```

Will AngularDart implicitly pass ServiceA to Logger upon instantiation even though Logger is not a component or directive? The AngularDart docs are unclear on this.

Comment: Shouldn't your code example look like `Logger(this._serviceA);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does AngularDart dependency injection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712318/how-does-angulardart-dependency-injection-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Logger` is instantiated by DI (AngularDart) it will try to resolve all dependencies (constructor arguments, also transitive) and pass them to the constructor or throw otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know if the same would true for the current scope? If scope is used in some class which isn't a component or directive, would DI try to resolve that too?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "current scope". I don't think there's  are exceptions. If you request an instance from DI (or Angular does implicitly) it tries to resolve constructor arguments. Can you provide a concrete code example to demonstrate what you mean?