# Has Angular.dart directive an equivalent to AngularJS's `restrict`

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In AngularJS there is an attribute for directives (and others) to specify if it can be instantiated by an element name or an attribute - like `restrict:EA` for element AND attribute.

The file [angular.dart / lib / directive / ng_a.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/132b49e49c9d8c49f9475950c98e0fd4487e702a/lib/directive/ng_a.dart) contains a comment `* @restrict E` which indicates the directive is for the `<A> element`.

Is `restrict` not necessary in Angular.dart?
What is the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, Angular.dart doesn't have `restrict`, so please disregard the comment in ng_a.dart, it's probably just a copy-paste from JS version. All directives/components/controllers use `selector`, so you normally need to be very specific. If you need an equivalent of `restrict:EA`, you could apply two annotations on the class. Ex:

```dart
@NgDirective(selector: 'foo')
@NgDirective(selector: '[foo]')
class FooDirective {

}
```