# What is the relationship btw "Angular 4" and angulardart?

Tags: angularjs, angular-dart, angular

I am very confusing btw upcoming angular4 and angulardart. Is angular4 just for angular-ts? What about angulardart upcoming versions and future? thanks a lot!

PS: 
I am just interested in if angular4 and angulardart have any relationships or not. And wondering If angular4 and future angulardart will share any codes, features, designs,  etc... I knew the difference btw angular2 and angulardart, and my question mainly focuses on the relationship btw angular4 and angulardart. Thanks.

Comment: read here: [http://news.dartlang.org/2016/07/angulardart-is-going-all-dart.html](http://news.dartlang.org/2016/07/angulardart-is-going-all-dart.html)

Comment: @PierreDuc Thanks for your reply. I read that link before. It doesn't answer my question. I am wondering what the relationship is between angular4 and angulardart.

Answer (score 1):

Since about beta.17 Angular Dart and Angular TS are developed independently (see also the link above from PierreDuc).

While Angular 1.x and Angular >= 2 are entirely different frameworks, from version 2 on, a new major version only indicates that breaking changes were introduced according to http://semver.org/
See also [What is Angular 4 and from where I can learn more about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692462/what-is-angular-4-and-from-where-i-can-learn-more-about-it/41692502#41692502)

For differences between Angular TS and Dart see also [What's the difference between AngularJS 2 and Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880844/whats-the-difference-between-angularjs-2-and-dart/40882199#40882199)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Do you mean angular4 will have no relationship to angulardart? If the answer is yes, angulardart should really change its name, because angular and angulardart will become entirely different in the future.

Comment: No, they won't become entirely different. The template syntax is mostly the same and both are developed by Google teams and they talk to each other ;-)

Comment: Is angular4 just for angular-ts? Do angulardart and angular4 share anything? What is upcoming angulardart? angulardart3? I really can not find any useful information online about angulardart plan. thanks.

Comment: For Dart a 3.0.0-alpha.x version is currently available. The [changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) provides some information. For Dart there is not so much information available as for TS.