# Angular and Angular Dart - which framework is recommended for the web development?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I am little bit confused about the difference between the latest Angular version and Angular Dart. Looks like both have same syntax and implementation style. So what is the intention behind the google for a new framework? I think it makes too confusion to outside. As per Angular Dart documentation

> [AngularDart](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular) is a web app framework that focuses on productivity,
>   performance, and stability

From my understanding Angular also offering the same for the web development and mainly focus on performance.

Can anyone help me understand- When to use Angular Dart and Angular? There is one link I saw from stack overflow which is comparing to Angular js

[Differences between Angular.js and Angular.dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993377/differences-between-angular-js-and-angular-dart)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no general answer. It mostly depends on your requirements and preferences.

An attempt:

If you want to use the Dart language, then you probably also want to use the Dart flavor of Angular, otherwise probably rather the TypeScript flavor.

The two versions are diverging notably since they were split and developed independently in May 2016.

There is nothing shared between these versions. For example 3rd party components work only with the flavor they are built for.

If you're into Dart, for example because you already built a mobile app using Flutter, then you probably want to reuse bigger parts of the code for the web version of your app. This works well with AngularDart.

If this is not the case you probably want to use the TypeScript version.

Angular Dart has some notable advantages for building large scale web applications because it has a stronger type system (your mileage might vary depending on your preferences). 
If you depend on 3rd party components, then the TypeScript flavor has probably more to offer for you. The Dart community is still small compared to the TypeScript community.

Comment: do you know about any performance differences between the two? Is there any measurable difference in initial page load times for angular vs angulardart apps?

Comment: FWIW, I did a lighthouse analysis on https://hnpwa.dartlang.org/ vs https://angular2-hn.firebaseapp.com/news/1 (both hacker news readers built with angular, dart vs typescript) and the dart app got a slightly better performance score and a considerably better SEO score