# Usage of <content> in angular.dart components?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

The method mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19818178/194642 does not seem to work anymore. How does one use web component's  element in angular.dart component?

```
@Component(
selector: "custom-elem",
template: "<div id='container-elem'> <content></content></div>")
class CustomElem extends ShadowRootAware{
  onShadowRoot(_) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Now, I would expect the following html fragment:

```
<custom-elem> 
  <span>Sample content</span>
</custom-elem>
```

to result in following within `#shadow-root`:

```
<div id='container-elem'>
  <content> 
    <span>Sample content</span>
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code snippets that demonstrate what you want to do?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added a sample snippet

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question or your expected result correctly but the `<content>` tag works the way that `<span>Sample content</span>` are children of `<custom-elem>` where `<div id='container-elem'>` is put in the Shadow DOM of `<custom-elem>` **before** the children and `</div>` in the Shadow DOM of `<custom-elem>` **after** the children but the `<span>` is in the light DOM like it would be when used like

```dart
<div> 
  <span>Sample content</span>
</div>
```

When you inspect the Shadow DOM of `<custom-elem>` there should just be the `template` part of your Angular component.